# Binding different IP to each WebRequest does not work

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have got 5 different IPs that I need to bind with different web requests.

Please see the sample code below. The Call1() works perfectly. But When I try to use List< Task > in Call2() then it binds wrong IP to the requests (I double check IPs in the IIS logs of the requested site).

Any help please!!!

```
    class Program
    {

        private static string[] IPs = new string[] { "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx" };
        private static string Url = "http://myfakedomain.com/{0}.aspx";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Call1();
            Call2();
        }

        static void Call1()
        {
            WebHandler web = new WebHandler();

                foreach (var ip in IPs)
                {
                    web.MakeWebRequest(String.Format(Url,ip), ip);
                }
        }

        static void Call2()
        {
            WebHandler web = new WebHandler();
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

                foreach (var ip in IPs)
                {
                   var ipCopy = ip;
                    tasks.Add(Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => web.MakeWebRequest(String.Format(Url, ipCopy ), ipCopy )));
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

    }

    public class WebHandler
    {
        public bool MakeWebRequest(string Url, string IP)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
            request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) => new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 0);

            request.KeepAlive = false;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Below is the IIS log for Call2()

```
2012-10-23 01:53:20 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx GET /xxx.xxx.xx.244.aspx - 80 - xxx.xxx.xx.242 - 200 0 0 1185
2012-10-23 01:53:20 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx GET /xxx.xxx.xx.241.aspx - 80 - xxx.xxx.xx.242 - 200 0 0 1201
2012-10-23 01:53:21 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx GET /xxx.xxx.xx.243.aspx - 80 - xxx.xxx.xx.242 - 200 0 0 608
2012-10-23 01:53:21 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx GET /xxx.xxx.xx.242.aspx - 80 - xxx.xxx.xx.242 - 200 0 0 624
2012-10-23 01:53:21 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx GET /xxx.xxx.xx.245.aspx - 80 - xxx.xxx.xx.242 - 200 0 0 218
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common confusion with variable closures in foreach loops when you are dealing with lambda expressions. Essentially if you change you Call2() code to below it should work as expected. If you are interested in why exactly it is happening check out [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for an excellent explanation.

```
static void Call2()
{
    WebHandler web = new WebHandler();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var ip in IPs)
    {
        var ipCopy = ip;
        tasks.Add(Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => web.MakeWebRequest(String.Format(Url, ipCopy), ipCopy)));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Interesting: I would update the question to mention that you have tried this and put you doing the 'var ipCopy = ip;' in the Call2 example code since this is the first thing most people will think of given your current Call2 code.